# Issue with resizing the image in product view page (media.phtml) magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to resize image in product view page, but after the image has resized, white spaces come along in left and right both the sides (width), in resize function I gave the value 338,474, but It comes with white spaces. For that I applied function `keepFrame(false)`.

But after applying that, my image height remains same, but width changes to 271. What should I do? Below is my code.

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image')->keepFrame(false)->resize(338,474);?>" alt='' title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel());?>" />
```

I tried `keepFrame(false)` both before and after `resize(338,474)`.
Please, if any body can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass your height and width in following function `resize`

```
$_img = '<img src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(338, 474).'" alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'" title="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'" />';
```

Comment: Not working, I mean it is displaying the image, but white spaces are there ... :(

Comment: are you uploading images with size less than `338x474` ?

Answer (score -1):

Try to do the following steps, (let's say you want 150 width):

1. Go and open default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml.
2. Now On line 54 find the delete the ‘width’ and ‘height’ attributes in the  tag.
3. On the same line (54), find.

   $_image->getFile()->resize(150, 150);

All good. Simply replace one of these numbers with 0 and the image will auto scale. e.g.:

```
$_image->getFile()->resize(150, 0);
```

It will give you images 150 pixels wide, but the height will vary according to the original image ratio.

Hope that helps.

Comment: what if I want to keep height and width exactly 338,474, Is it possible??

Comment: Are you uploading images with smaller size? Also, did you check your CSS if it doesn't have `white` background.